# Create Database If Not Exists with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I'm trying to create a database-install PHP file that first attempts to create a database if it does not already exist using a PDO prepared statement that I execute, and then I would like to connect to this. Is this how I would do it? Or is there something I'm missing here?

```
$mysql = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost", $dbusername, $dbpassword);
$pstatement = $mysql->prepare("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $dbname");
$pstatment->execute();
$dbconn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbusername, $dbpassword);
```

Comment: why would do you want to create a database with PDO? Do you understand that you are NOT using prepared statement here (although you can't but anyway)?

Comment: @Your Common Sense Normally I would just use phpMyAdmin to actually create the database but for some random reason our professor wants us to do it this way.

Comment: @oGeez, thanks. I just updated it.

Comment: Okay, but I'm in agreement with @YourCommonSense. I can't think of a time when you would need to create this way.

Comment: This works, assuming the user that the user you are authenticating with *has* database `CREATE` privileges. I assume you tried already - did you receive an error? If not you could wrap the statements in a try/catch to get some visibility on the error: `try { /* PDO statements */} catch (PDOException $e) { echo $e->getMessage(); }`. I'd like to add... creating databases like this feels sorta... inadvisable.

Comment: Me neither. :(
I'm not sure why he wants it this way. Is it possible?

Comment: Your professor may want you to research using PDO and find out what it is designed to do,its pros & cons. After this research its time to ask your him why he wants you to use PDO for this.

Comment: If you are creating a new database for a new user on your web app (as an example), you might want to use PDO to create the database.  Not because it allows for prepared statements here (because it doesn't) but because you're using PDO for the rest of the entire project.  There's no point in making different kinds of connections, or mixing up code.  If you're going to use PDO to interact with the database, you might as well use PDO to create the database.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Slightly more sensible and safe code.

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost", $dbusername, $dbpassword);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$dbname = "`".str_replace("`","``",$dbname)."`";
$pdo->query("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $dbname");
$pdo->query("use $dbname");
```

Comment: I just tried mine and it worked, but I'm gonna give this to you because yours is safer.